# Computer not reconizing ubuntu boot file. Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: boot, 13.04, grub2

After trying many times to install Ubuntu 12.04 onto my computer and it not working I gave 1 last shot to the latest software(Being 13.04), and it installed but it wont boot unless I have the install disk in my disk tray. I also believe that it is not saving what I do and just giving me a fresh version of Ubuntu every time. I saw some things about changing the /etc/default/grub.d file or something like that, but I am still not sure. If someone can help me that would be great.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04. My bad

Comment: New computer? Perhaps it has a UEFI BIOS, in which case you have to fiddle to get it to boot.  see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: As it worked, i've posted it as the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

If this is a fairly recent model of computer it is likely that it has an UEFI BIOS.  You need to follow the guide, at [help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)